# NavigationLink and PresentationLink Error

Tags: ios, swiftui

I was working on SwiftUI tutorials from Apple's website.

Implemented demo from [this](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/composing-complex-interfaces) url.

It is throwing an error for NavigationLink and PresentationLink.

Below is my body paragraph code,

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {

                FeaturedLandmarks(landmarks: featured)
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    .clipped()
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                ForEach(categories.keys.sorted().identified(by: \.self)) { key in
                    CategoryRow(categoryName: key, items: self.categories[key]!)

                }
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkList()) {
                    Text("See All")
                }
                }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Featured"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    PresentationLink(destination: Text("User Profile")) {
                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .accessibility(label: Text("User Profile"))
                            .padding()
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Xcode 11 beta 3. The name of the components you mention was chaged after beta 2.